# Every time Libvirt VM is started, AppArmor profile for it gets removed

Tags: virtualization, apparmor

When I create Libvirt virtual machine with

```
virsh create
```

`/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-142341234-234123-4124-123-4234` and `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-142341234-234123-4124-123-4234.files` gets created. Then, when I save and start VM again, those files are getting removed - at every launch, even if I made edits in them.

Whats appropriate way to modify the apparmor profiles for Libvirt machine on ubuntu?

Comment: These files are generated and not meant to be edited manually. Why are you trying to change them? Perhaps there is some alternative approach to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

first of all Michael is right, those files are generated and not meant to be edited.

To add custom rules you'd need to generally allow (for all guests) things right now. To do so you'd need to edit the conffile delivered by the package at

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu
```

Newer versions (>=18.10) have a local override defined to avoid any conffile questions on upgrades.

```
/etc/apparmor.d/local/abstractions/libvirt-qemu
```

I'm eager to provide per-guest overrides but for quite some time I'm waiting until apparmor will fully support optional include files. You'll see when that happens at [bug 1745114](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1745114)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ISO image was on an mounted storage, so the solution was

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.lib.libvirt.virt-aa-helper
```

The you may add the entries:

```
/media/DATA/Downloads/Distros/** r, 
/{media,mnt,opt,srv}/** r
```

[Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibvirtApparmor)